# How to print colored logs in Flutter or Dart projects?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, logging, printing

In Flutter or Dart projects texts printed with **print** function are colored like other texts. How to print colored texts? My editor is VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package named [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) which prints texts colored and well structured. You can use it as following:

```dart
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

void main() {
  final logger = Logger();

  logger.e('Error');
  logger.i('Info');
  logger.w('Warning');
  logger.d('Debug');
  logger.f('Fatal');
  logger.log(Level.error, 'Error message');
}
```

The result in the console:

[image: In the console you can see easily your logs]